# SQL count joins distinct by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, count, left-join

I have a problem where I need to JOIN on the same table multiple time and count the JOINS.

here is the database setup ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/738b4/1)
):

```
CREATE TABLE state
(
  [t_id] int,
  [true_id] int,
  [false_id] int,
  [msg] varchar(32) 
);

INSERT INTO state
  (t_id, true_id, false_id, msg)
VALUES
  (5, 6, 7, 'CASE_1'),
  (10, 11, 12, 'CASE_2'),
  (20, 21, 22, 'CASE_N'),
  (30, 31, 32, 'FOOOO');

CREATE TABLE step
(
      [id] int,
      [f_id] int,
      [state_type] int,
      [state_value] int
);

INSERT INTO step
    (id,f_id,state_type, state_value)
VALUES
    (1, 5, 5, 7),
    (2, 5, 5, 7),
    (3, 5, 5, 6),

    (4, 5, 10, 12),
    (5, 5, 10, 12),
    (6, 5, 10, 11),

    (7, 6, 10, 12),
    (8, 6, 10, 12),

    (9, 7, 20, 21),
    (10, 7, 20, 21),

    (11, 7, 30, 32),
    (12,7, 30, 31);
```

here is my current query:

```
SELECT state.msg, 
  COUNT(state_true.true_id) AS Trues,
  COUNT(state_false.false_id) AS Falses
FROM state
  INNER JOIN step ON state.t_id = step.state_type
  LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_true ON step.state_value = state_true.true_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN state AS state_false ON step.state_value = state_false.false_id
GROUP BY state.msg, step.f_id
```

**And here what I get:**

```
msg     Trues   Falses
CASE_1  1       2
CASE_2  1       2
CASE_2  0       2
CASE_N  2       0
FOOOO   1       1
```

**And here what i need:**

```
msg     Trues   Falses
CASE_1  1       0
CASE_2  1       1
CASE_N  1       0
FOOOO   1       0
```

**For Explanation:**

I need to count how many trues and fails are per **state_type and f_id** combination.

There are 6 entries with the `f_id = 5` -> `(1,2,3,4,5,6)`. If there is a entry with the same `(f_id,state_type)` combination, only the last one should be counted. So for `f_id 5` the entries `1,2,4,5` should not be taken into the count, as they are *overwritten* by `3` and `6`.

So after processing the first 6 entries there should be `CASE_1` `true => 1` `false => 0` and `CASE_2` `true => 1` `false => 0`

__ EDIT __

```
 TABLE step:

(1, 5, 5, 7),  -- do not count
(2, 5, 5, 7),  -- do not count
(3, 5, 5, 6),  -- this is the last entry with 
               -- (f_id,state_type) => (5,5) combination. 
               -- it overwrites the 2 previous ones => count CASE_1 true

(4, 5, 10, 12), -- do not count
(5, 5, 10, 12), -- do not count
(6, 5, 10, 11), -- count CASE_2 true

(7, 6, 10, 12), -- do not count
(8, 6, 10, 12), -- count CASE_2 false

(9, 7, 20, 21),  -- do not count
(10, 7, 20, 21), -- count CASE_N false

(11, 7, 30, 32), -- do not count
(12,7, 30, 31);  -- count FOOOO true
```

Comment: Very good way of presenting question.(With SQL fiddle and creation script). But, i am having hard time to understand explanation.

Comment: well presented but I'm also feels the same :(

Comment: why are you joining with true_id and false_id.. is that needed?

Comment: I do that to get to columns in the result. one for the trues and one for the falses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your intent, but maybe the query below might be what you want? Given your sample data it seems to produce the right output.

```
SELECT state.msg, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN true_id  = state_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Trues,
  SUM(CASE WHEN false_id = state_value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Falses
FROM state
JOIN step ON state.t_id = step.state_type
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) mid FROM step GROUP BY f_id, state_type) a ON a.mid = step.id
GROUP BY state.msg;
```

Please give it a try. If I misunderstood I'll remove the answer.

Comment: Yea this looks nice :)